# Para que servem as dependências num framework?

Tags: framework, dependências

Sou completamente novo nessa questão de framework e não consigo achar resposta alguma no google sobre esta pergunta.

**O que são e para que servem as dependências? O que elas fazem?**

Answer (score 3):

Dependência é um termo genérico que indica que o framework necessidade de uma ou mais bibliotecas(classes ou outros artefatos) especificas para funcionar corretamente.

Por exemplo, plugins do jquery geralmente dependem que o próporio jquery esteja 'instalado' no projeto sem ele o plugin não funcionaria.

Várias linguagens possuem algumas ferramentas que facilitam a instalação e manipulação dessas bibliotecas que são conhecidas como gerenciadores de dependências. Algumas tarefas que os gerenciadores oferecem são, pesquisa das bibliotecas, donwload, instalação e tratamente das dependências, isso significa que as bibliotecas serão instaladas na versão compatível com o framework usado no projeto. Alguns exemplos dessas ferramentes são, composer, maven e de forma mais generica os gerenciadores de pacotes do linux.

Comment: cara, muito obrigado. agora sim eu entendi. ótima resposta

Answer (score 2):

Acho que este é um caso onde uma imagem pode valer mil palavras. Esse é um mapa básico de dependências do [framework Nyan](https://github.com/bucknellu/Nyan):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse framework se propõe a oferecer uma estrutura capaz de expor uma API RESTful baseada em armazenamento de dados em estilo ORM.

Perceba que o framework por si só é apenas um coordenador - ele não sabe como expor interfaces REST ou acessar dados.

Estas ações ocorrem nas dependências, que são os verdadeiros agentes em seus respectivos domínios. Uma chamada REST típica seria então uma orquestração de funcionalidades pelo framework:

> GET /data/users/256

- *Microsoft WebAPI 2.0* recebe a requisição, e a repassa para o *framework*;
- O framework mapeia a requisição para uma classe ORM previamente definida, `Users`;
- *StackExchange Redis* checa se o dado está em cache ou não; se negativo,
- *StackExchange Dapper* gera uma requisição para o banco de dados;
- O *cliente de banco de dados* (MySQL, Oracle ou SQL Server, por exemplo) envia a requisição para o servidor;
- O framework então:

  - serializa o resultado via *NetwonSoft JSON*
  - Armazena o conteúdo serializado no Redis
  - Utiliza NetMQ para notificar os outros servidores da atualização
- *Microsoft WebAPI 2.0* retorna o resultado serializado para o cliente.

Note então que a ação acima acionou 7 dependências.

De maneira simplificada, as *dependências* são módulos que sabem lidar com aspectos específicos de implementação; e *frameworks* são orquestradores de fluxos e funcionalidades.

Comment: Essa ficou boa e explica legal. Eu estava quase pra responder.